# Question still featured after bounty expires

Tags: bug, bounty

How can [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14897/where-to-buy-my-favorite-magnetic-chess-set) still be in the Featured tab? Its bounty ended ten days ago, according to the [timeline](https://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/14897/timeline).

**EDIT**: now that a [new question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/15060/chess-study-methods-memorisation-techniques-from-before-the-computer-based-srs) has been bountied, it's gone. Could be some caching issue, but let's see what happens seven days from now.